# k-Nearest Neighbors rundown

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, machine-learning

I'm trying to follow an example on k-Nearest Neighbors and I'm not sure about the numpy command syntax. I'm supposed to be doing a matrix-wise distance calculation and the code given is

```
def classify(inputVector, trainingData,labels,k):
     dataSetSize=trainingData.shape[0]
     diffMat=tile(inputVector,(dataSetSize,1))-trainingData
     sqDiffMat = diffMat**2
     sqDistances = sqDiffMat.sum(axis=1)
     distances = sqDistances**0.5
     sortedDistIndicies = distances.argsort()     
for i in range(k):
    voteIlabel = labels[sortedDistIndicies[i]]
    classCount[voteIlabel] = classCount.get(voteIlabel,0) + 1
    sortedClassCount = sorted(classCount.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
    return sortedClassCount[0][0]

def createDataSet():
     group = array([[1.0,1.1],[1.0,1.0],[0,0],[0,0.1]])
     labels = ['A','A','B','B']
     return group, labels
```

my question is how does `sqDistances**0.5` amount to the distance equation `((A[0]-B[0])+(A[1]-B[1]))^1/2`? I don't follow how tile influences it specifically how the matrix is made from (datasetsize,1)-training data.

Comment: perhaps you could show a small sample of your inputVector and trainingData, which one can only assume are arrays

Comment: that's the rest of the code segment.Hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope the following will explain the working.

Numpy tile : https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html

Using this function, you are creating matrix from input vector same to the shape of training data. From this matrix you are subtracting training data which will give you some part from what you mentioned say `test[0]-train[0]` i.e. element wise difference.

Then you squared each obtained element by using `diffMat**2` and then taken sum along `axis = 1` (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html). This resulted in equations like `(test[0] - train[0])^2 + (test[1] - train[1])^2`.

Next by taking `sqDistances**0.5` , it will give Euclidean distance.

To calculate Euclidean distance, this might be helpful
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean.html#scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean

Comment: from the reference I have discerned from the format that .shape[0] leaves the row value and reps for (tile) in this case is (dataSetSize,1))-trainingData. I cannot see why that is. also how axis =1

Comment: what I really want to know is how datSetSize is defined when it is used in tile. I'm not sure what datSetSize,1 does

Comment: For subtracting matrices you need both matrices should be of same size. So you need to know how may training samples are there in training data. This is why datSetSize is there. 

Refer to link provided for Numpy tile, the last example on the page shows what datSetSize,1 does.  It makes copy of input vector to "datSetSize" times.